# How to Create and SSH Tunnel to another machine through mine in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh-tunnel

I need to created an SSH Tunnel to another machine, where the local machine would be the "remote server" in most examples.

`tunneled Machine =====> local machine ======> private server`

I've looked at the package `sshtunnel`, but I've only been able to figure out the following diagram.

`local machine =====> remote machine ======> private server`

Is there a way to use sshtunnel to complete the first diagram?